# Getting a strange seg fault from imported queue.front()

Tags: c++, algorithm, segmentation-fault, breadth-first-search

So I am currently working on a graph abstract data type for my CS163 class.  Everything else for this program works awesome BUT the depth-first traversal of the graph.  When testing, I add all the vertices I want, then connect them as I need to.  I check and everything is indeed linked as it should be so we are good to go.  I jump into this function below, given the name of the friend(vertex) to start from.  The line I commented "*current_buddy = myQueue.front();" is the line I found in GDB to be the offending piece of code that causes a seg fault.  Also using GDB, I was able to successfully print the proper vertex using "p myQueue.front()"

So perhaps a sample test to give a bit more context.  say I have the points a,b,c,d, and e.  a is connected to c,d, and e.  b is connected to c.  I want to start at vertex "a" for this test.  Passing in a to the function, it finds the proper index with the find_location function which simply returns said index integer.  It will then push that vertex onto the queue and mark that vertex as visited so that upon traversal, I don't return to that point to push it onto the queue again.  I create a node "current" that is attached to the first node in the edge list for the "a" vertex.  When it goes into the first loop, I use the previously created vertex "current_buddy" to point to the first object in the queue, which is the vertex "a."  This is the point that the program hits a seg fault and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on with that line of code that would cause this.

Both "vertex" and "node" are structs I have created and the queue I am using is from the standard library #include queue [more on the queue bit here if needed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/)  Any and all information would be greatly appreciated!  Obviously since this is a school assignment, I don't expect anyone to just give me the answer but I am lost at the moment.

```
bool graph::breadth_first(char * start)
{
    if(adjacency_list[0].buddy_name == NULL)
        return false;

    int location = find_location(start);
    queue<vertex> myQueue;

    myQueue.push(adjacency_list[location]);
    adjacency_list[location].visited = true;

    node * current = adjacency_list[location].head;
    vertex * current_buddy = NULL;

    while(myQueue.empty() == false)
    {
        *current_buddy = myQueue.front();//THIS LINE SEG FAULTS
        cout << "THIS IS A FRIEND IN THE BREADTH-FIRST TRAVERSAL" << current_buddy->buddy_name << endl;
        current = current_buddy->head;
        myQueue.pop();
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            if(current->connected_buddy->visited == false)
            {
                current_buddy = current->connected_buddy;
                location = find_location(current_buddy->buddy_name);
                myQueue.push(adjacency_list[location]);
                adjacency_list[location].visited = true;
                current = current->next;
            }

        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; adjacency_list[i].buddy_name != NULL; ++i)
    {
        adjacency_list[i].visited = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Look a couple of lines above the one that crashes, where you initialize `current_buddy` to `NULL`. Now think about what happens when you try to dereference a null pointer...

Comment: that was an edit I made attempting to add some consistency to my tests :/ even if i dont set it to NULL initially, it still gives the same problem

Comment: Why is `current_buddy`a pointer? Shouldn't it be just a `vertex` ?

Comment: it's a pointer to a vertex object.  My thinking was that I would have it point to the vertex that myQueue.front() returns by reference

Comment: And if you don't initialize the variable, its value will be *indeterminate* and you still have UB when you try to dereference the pointer.

Comment: UB? could you please explain?

Comment: "UB" is short for [*Undefined Behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and is a common cause behind crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDIT: For the first part of this question, the solution/answer provided by Joachim may perform better. I just like avoid pointer when possible.)

You could try:

```
vertex * current_buddy = NULL;

while(myQueue.empty() == false)
{
    vertex front_buddy = myQueue.front();
    cout << "THIS IS A FRIEND IN THE BREADTH-FIRST TRAVERSAL" << front_buddy.buddy_name << endl;
    current = front_buddy.head;
```

BTW - I think you need to check for null here:

```
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->connected_buddy == NULL)
        {
            // add error handling
        }
        else
        {
            // normal code
        }
     }
```

So that you don't get another crash

This part

```
   while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->connected_buddy->visited == false)
        {
            // your code

            current = current->next;
        }

    }
```

looks like an endless loop in case `current->connected_buddy->visited` is true.

Maybe you want

```
   while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->connected_buddy->visited == false)
        {
            // your code

        }

        // Moved out of the if-statement
        current = current->next;
    }
```

Comment: well actually, when the edges are first made, they can only point to a valid vertex :)  That's why I didn't bother including it here.

Comment: Your edit where you added the lines about current = current->next were absolutely true :)  thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. As you probably noticed from all this, pointers can be hard to use and often leads to unexpected results, memory leaks and crashes. If possible you should consider a design where you avoid pointer and use the standard containers instead. Of cause that's not always possible but it is always worth to consider whether the design can be made without pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work as you expect, but a quick fix might be to use the address-of operand and actually assign the *pointer* instead of dereferencing it:

```
current_buddy = &myQueue.front();
```

Comment: that actually did the trick!  Though now I seem to be seg faulting on my while loop for checking if current != NULL.  I'm not really sure what the issue is with it :/

Comment: Ok, so using the above test example I provided in my initial comment, when running, it displays "THIS IS A FRIEND IN THE BREADTH-FIRST TRAVERSALa" and "THIS IS A FRIEND IN THE BREADTH-FIRST TRAVERSALc" then hangs forever

Comment: @BlackDahlia1147 - Maybe you have a circular reference so that `current->next` never turns into NULL. Can you add a `cout`in that loop?

Comment: Or maybe the line `current = current->next` is at the wrong place. In case `visited` is true, you'll never change `current`and will loop forever.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but at the point that the program seg faults, we will have the current node linked to the current_buddy vertex's head, which would have a single edge (linking it to a).  I'll see what i can do about displaying current there

Comment: the program is making it through a's edge list successfully and went on to vertex b as planned then seg faulting

Comment: oh man, you're right about that!  Lemme fix that up and see what that does for me

Comment: That 100% fixed it and I am hitting each vertex perfectly as I should be!  Thanks so much for the help and for catching that mistake with current->next.  Now I can just finish up with displaying all the other information!  Have a good night man/woman!

Answer (score 0):

It's segfault because you are attempting to deference a NULL pointer.

```
vertex * current_buddy = NULL;

while(myQueue.empty() == false)
{
    // V de-referencing a NULL pointer
    *current_buddy = myQueue.front();//THIS LINE SEG FAULTS
```

You should change it to

```
// vertex * current_buddy = NULL; // < Remove this line

while(myQueue.empty() == false)
{
    vertex *current_buddy = &myQueue.front();
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the one from Joachim which were already here?

Comment: he may have been writing it out at the same time :) but I would like to say that i responded to the aforementioned first answer so if you could check out my comments there, that would be great :) but i appreciate the help!

Comment: By the time I added this answer, I haven't notice his answer. By the way, I added the explanation for the seg fault.

Comment: ah yes, that part made sense!